# Somar valores de uma coluna com Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-directory

Ola estou iniciando os estudos com Ruby On Rails, e estou fazendo uma aplicação que gerencia gastos. Bem o que eu preciso fazer somar todos os gastos da coluna "valor" e mostrar na view.

Estou tentando o seguinte na ActiveRecord

```
def total
    divida.sum("valor * ")
end
```

Essa seria a maneira correta? como faço pra mostrar na view?

Desde já agradeço a atenção!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer como o citado na outra resposta, só que nunca chame um método de um model em uma view, pois model não comunica com view, e isso é um dos fundamentos do MVC. Você pode chamar esse método no seu controle, referenciar em uma variável e utiliza-la em sua view

no seu model:

```
class Payment
  def self.total
    self.sum(:value)
  end
end
```

no seu controller:

```
class PaymentsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @sum_of_payments = Payment.total
  end
end
```

na sua view em app/payments/index.html.erb:

```
<%= @sum_of_payments %>
```

ps: evite escrever código em português, e pior ainda, misturar inglês com português.

Comment: Obrigado, me ajudou a entender melhor ainda

Answer (score 0):

A classe que representa o seu model pode conter um método de classe que calcula a soma de todos os valores de dívida. Estou supondo que existe uma tabela `dividas` em seu banco de dados, que contém uma coluna `valor`.

```
class Divida < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.total
    self.sum(:valor)
  end
end
```

Então na sua view (por exemplo o arquivo `app/views/divida/index.html.erb` ), você pode chamar `Divida.total` que irá retornar o total de todas as dívidas.